# Unable to add extension to azure devops from marketplace

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-marketplace

I am trying to add an extension to my Azure Devops organisation.  I was able to do this once before but now I get a message in the Market Place that no organisations can be found that I am a member of.

I have followed the trouble shooting guide for this issue as follows:

I have verified I am signed in to Azure Devops as the owner
I have verified that I am a member of Project Collection Administrators
I have verified that I am signed in to Market Place as the same user as DevOps

I have had the organisation since 2008 so it has been migrated from older incarnations of Azure DevOps over the years.  Not sure if that is related.

Everything I have found here on SO and generally via Google says I should be able to add the extension but cannot.  Anyone offer any suggestions as to how I can resolve this?

Comment: You could not install all the extensions or just could not install a specific extension? If the specify one, please share the name to us, so that we could test it on my side. And have you tried login out the marketplace and Azure Devops and re-login?

Comment: Cannot install any extensions.  I have posted in the developer community too since posting this, but the only solution offered is to make someone else an admin and get them to install it.  Not really addressing the fact that I am the owner of the org and can't install.  I have tried logging in and out many times, clearing my cache, using different browsers.